# How does the compiler use 'yield return' to build a class

Tags: c#

In specific, if I say:

```
    public static IEnumerable<String> Data()
    {
        String connectionString = "...";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            IDataReader reader = new SqlCommand("", connection).ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
                yield return String.Format("Have a beer {0} {1}!", reader["First_Name"], reader["Last_Name"]);

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

How does the compiler go about generating a concrete enumerable class out of this?

Comment: It's black magic, I tell you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It builds a state machine, basically:

- It creates a private nested class, with instance variables corresponding to the local variables in your method, and a `state` variable to keep track of where it's got to
- The state machine implements `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` - the `MoveNext()` method gets to the right bit of the logic (based on `state`) and sets an instance variable to keep track of the last-yielded value (the `Current` property)
- The compiler creates a "skeleton" method with the same signature as your original, which creates an instance of the state machine

See [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) for more details. Also note that async/await in C# 5 is built with a lot of the same ideas (although there are various implementation differences).

Comment: You might want to address `yield return` within the `using`?

Comment: @manojlds: Nothing special about that, really.  The state machine is built AFTER `using` is broken into its initialization and cleanup components.  Exception `finally` handlers in general (not just `using`) are moved to the `Dispose` method of the generated class.

Comment: @BenVoigt - OP says specific example, and the yield return within using, special or not, seemed worth mentioning.